# TOR key verification issue

Tags: command-line, firefox, tor

I am about as new to Linux as it is possible to be. I am also relatively ignorant of the inner workings of software and OS's and of networking in general.
I recently downloaded and installed UBUNTU 16.04.02 LTS on my old Lenovo Thinkpad E320, effectively reviving what I had thought to be a dead machine.
My knowledge of UBUNTU, garnered over the last couple of days, is essentially limited to:

- The terminal is the underlying command interface of Linux, it is used to issue commands to the OS;
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens the terminal;
- The `sudo` prefix on a command issues admin privileges with the command;
- Various GUI functions as learned through mouse-over text.

I wish to use TOR with Firefox for privacy sake but encountered the failed key authorization issue when i installed the TOR browser.

[image]

I tried going through the other threads here, as well as other instructional web pages I've found, but don't even understand, or am at least uncertain of, some of the terminology.

The following example should be indicative of my level of confusion and uncertainty.
The launch with TOR button offered by the Firefox plug-in returns

[image]

The first step was, obviously, simple enough for me, however...

- Q1-Is a "local directory" merely any folder on my laptop, or does it need to be extracted to a specific place for the OS to find it?;
- Q2-Does "open a terminal in the root directory" actually imply a difference in the function of the terminal depending on where you open it from somehow, or is it simply indicating a need to run the proceeding command using the `sudo` prefix?;
- Q3-Is this set of instructions even directly related to the key auth. issue this post is actually about?

Any help offered here on this issue will be greatly appreciated. Also, any suggestions on general tutorial pages aimed at users with my epic noob levels will also be gratefully accepted.

Comment: The really practical way to run TOR browser is with TOR Bundle. Just extract the file to any location you want (and have permissions), open the extract folder and double-click "Start TOR". This way it isn't really installed (runs from its own folder) and can be used simultaneously with the "normal" Firefox. Alternatively, if you really want it installed like any other app, you can and should install it directly from the repositories using Ubuntu Software or terminal. You don't need and shouldn't do the things you're trying to do.

Comment: Apologies for my obtuseness, I'm afraid I'm going to need further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, thank you for your help Michael. Although it was initially more confusing, through no fault of yours, your post did lead directly to me solving my problem myself.
My fundamental misunderstanding, reflected in my OP, was that I was conflating 2 different things.

The signature verification failure, (image 1) resulted from my attempt to install what I had thought was the full TOR browser, but was actually the "TOR Browser Bundle". I had found and installed this through the "Ubuntu Software" button on the sidebar, it being one of 3 results returned from a search within "Ubuntu Software" for "TOR Browser".

Image 2 was related only to the firefox extension named "open in tor browser" and was actually asking me to install a "native client" (/install.sh) which "helps the browser communicate with the OS". 
My error here was the initial assumption that "native client" was referring to a copy of the tor browser itself. This assumption in turn led me to thinking that my previous failed attempts to install what I thought was the full TOR Browser was the cause of this request to install the "native client".

Since reading your answer I have

- Uninstalled the "TOR Browser Bundle" and removed the extension from
  firefox.
- Downloaded "tor-browser-linux64-7.0.2_en-US.tar.xz" directly from
  the TOR site.
- Extracted "tor-browser-linux64-7.0.2_en-US.tar.xz" to the home directory
- Double clicked "TOR Browser" within the new "home/tor-browser_en-US" folder.

I now have a functional TOR browser, running using firefox.

I am, however, still somewhat confused, since the description of process in your answer that parallels my successful steps above seemed to be referring to the "TOR Bundle", while the steps as I took them were applied to the TOR Browser downloaded directly from the TOR site. I suspect I am still misunderstanding something, however am happy about the positive result regardless.

Thanks again for your help